# How to get PID by command line in python (windows)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Using `psutil.Process(PID)`, I can get the command line.

Like,

```
>>> import psutil
>>> p = psutil.Process(4510)
>>> p.cmdline()
['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver', '8081']
```

But, I want to know PID for a given command line.

Like,

```
>>> cmd = "python manage.py runserver 8081"
>>> p = psutil.some_method_which_takes_command_line(cmd)
>>> p.pid()
4510
```

How to achieve this?

**Note:**

What I trying to achieve from this is, restart the django server everyday at night. For that, I have planned to get PID of running django server by command line and kill it at night. After that I will run same command `cmd` again to start server.

Comment: You can find your process by name

Comment: @Wonka I have so many processes on same name. Is it possible to get PID from port number?

Comment: This answer might be useful
here is the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name) Try this

Comment: @AmitGupta It is by giving PID name, we can get process name, which is not related to my question.

Comment: ISTM that running a service or application on a schedule, with a forced termination and restart after a given number of hours is a job for the OS task scheduler, and it's a question for superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for this:

```
import time  # only here for sleep, you don't need it
import subprocess

cmd = ['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver', '8081']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

# something happens for a while here
time.sleep(1)

p.terminate()
# or p.kill() if you're on Linux and want to kill, not terminate the process
```

The question specifically asked about getting the PID from the process however, that can be done as well:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver', '8081']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
pid = p.pid
```

Be careful about obtaining a PID and just reusing it to kill a process later though, there's often better ways to go about getting rid of a process that needs removal or restarting.

Note that if you started the process with `shell=True`, the PID will be the PID of the shell process, not the program started in the shell. Refer to the documentation here https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I need is, restart the django server everyday at night. For that, I have planned to get PID of running django server by command line and kill it at night. After that I will run same command `cmd` again to start server. Can you update the answer accordingly?

Comment: @HumeshSindpure at this point, I don't think you're asking a question, I think you're asking me to do your job for you. I think the answer above tells you enough to get the job done. If you need to reboot a django server daily, I have two pieces of advice: #1. fix the code of the janky web app that breaks your server if you don't and #2. use the OS scheduler (`cron`, `Windows Scheduler`, etc.) to restart the web application server instead of a python script.

Comment: Sorry, for miss-communication. I don't need complete code for that. I just need the part of code where I'm struck. **Getting `PID` by giving command line as input.** Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can't get the pid of a command that was issued a lot earlier. If you're looking to save the pid to file when you start the server and then (a day) later use it to kill the process, you should probably still heed that advice. However, you could easily access the `.pid` of `p` - read the documentation of subprocess https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thanks, it works! You can add this information to answer. I will accept.